# Determine type of argument

Tags: c++, templates

Is it somehow possible to reflect the type of the argument of a function at compile time?

So that

```
int b = add(3, 6)
```

Would result in a template instantiation in the form of

```
int add(int a, int b) { return a + b }
```

out of some however declared function template

```
A add(A a, B b) { return a + b }
```

I don't know if that is possible with templates they do not really seem to be made for heavy meta-programming.

Comment: Missing semicolons in the question, the answers, everywhere.

Comment: The last statement isn't true. There even is a complete template meta programming library in Boost. Templates are wonderful for meta programming.

Comment: @aschepler: semicolons are the most superfluous thing in C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Templates do all their magic at compile time, but that seems to be quite adequate for what you're asking:

```
template <class T>
T add(T a, T b) {  return a + b; }
```

It does get a bit more complex when the two might not match, so (for example) you could add an `int` to a `double` and get a `double` result. The current standard doesn't really support that<sup>1</sup>; with C++0x you can look into `auto` and `decltype` for such tasks.

<sup>1</sup>Though Boost [`typeof`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/typeof.html) will often do the job.

Comment: I should have been a bit more precise with my question, probably auto is what I search. Or can I somehow else nest Templates? I have a templated class and I want for one Method to have an additional Template argument. `template<typename Type, int N>
class Vector;` and later `template<typename Type, int N, typename ScalarType>
Vector<Type, N> Vector<Type, N>::operator + (const ScalarType &scalar) const` doesn't really work out.

Comment: @nils: It would work out, except a template method inside a template class would take two `template` keywords: `template <typename Type, int N> template <typename ScalarType> Vector<Type, N> Vector<Type, N>::operator + (const ScalarType &scalar) const`

Answer (score 3):

```
template<typename T>
T add(T a, T b) { return a + b; }
```

Then you can call this with any built-in type (int, short, double, float, etc), and it will instantiate the function `add` at compile time, according to the type you use.

Note that if you split this into header/source, you will have trouble:

add.h:

```
template<typename T>
T add(T a, T b);
```

add.cpp:

```
template<typename T>
T add(T a, T b) { return a + b; }
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "add.h"

int a = 3;
int b = 5;
int i = add(a, b);
```

When you try to compile this, it will fail at link time.  Here's why.

Compiling `add.obj` does *not* instantiate the `add` template method -- because it's never called in add.cpp.  Compiling `main.obj` instantiates the function declaration -- but not the function body.  So at link time, it will fail to find the definition of the `add` method.

Simplest fix is to just put the entire template function in the header:

add.h:

```
template<typename T>
T add(T a, T b) { return a + b; }
```

and then you don't even need the add.cpp file at all.

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't this do what you're asking?

```
template <typename A, typename B>
A add(A a, B b) { return a + b; }
```

This is hardly "heavy meta-programming".

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly the sort of thing templates do.

```
template <typename T>
inline T add(T a, T b) { return a + b; }
```

Allowing two different types gets a little bit trickier but is also possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan on using anything other than simple types you want (in a header file):

```
template <typename A>
inline A add(const A& a, const A& b) { return a + b; }
```

Note the 'inline'.

As noted by others, the issue with mixed types is how to determine the return type from the argument types. Suppose we stick to simple types and have:

template 
inline A add(A a, B b) { return a + b; }

Then this fails (likely with only a warning):

```
double d = add(1, 1.5); // Sets d to 2.0
```

So you have to do some work. For example:

```
template<class A, class B>
struct Promote
{
};

template<class A>
struct Promote<A,A>
{
    typedef  A Type;
};

template<>
struct Promote<int, double>
{
    typedef double Type;
};

template<>
struct Promote<double, int>
{
    typedef double Type;
};
```

The add function becomes:

```
template<class A, class B>
inline typename Promote<A,B>::Type add(A a, B b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

What all this does for you is ensure that the return type is the one *you* specify for adding a given pair of types. This will work even for complex types.